# covering number and compactness

Tags: calculus, probability, metric-spaces

The following picture is what I extracted from the end of page 7 in http://www-personal.umich.edu/~romanv/papers/non-asymptotic-rmt-plain.pdf

[image]

My confusion is on the blue part: in 1-dimensional euclidean space, (-2,2) is not compact since it is not closed.  Then, by the blue part,  it seems for $X=(-2,2)$, $\mathcal{N(X,\epsilon)}=\infty$!!!, which is what I cannot understand.

Comment: The link seems to be broken. Could you fix that?

Answer (score 1):

It’s simply not true in general, as your example shows. It is true if the metric space $\langle X,d\rangle$ is complete, by virtue of the theorem that a metric space is compact if and only if it’s both complete and totally bounded. By definition a metric space is totally bounded if and only if $\mathcal{N}(X,\epsilon)$ is finite for each $\epsilon>0$.

$(-2,2)$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$, so it does have complete metrics, but in those metrics it’s not totally bounded; in the usual metric it’s totally bounded but not complete.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation.

Comment: @olivia: You’re welcome.